# Sum a column in awk and print each line of said column divided by the sum

Tags: awk

I have a column of counts that I want to transform into frequencies. This sums the first column and prints the sum:

```
awk '{ sum+=$1 } END {print sum}'
```

However, I can't quite figure out how to divide each line of said file with the sum (in one-liner format). Bonus points for being able to specify the number of decimals.

Example input:

0
0
0
0
1
0
5
0

Output should be:

0
0
0
0
0.166666667
0
0.833333333
0

And preferably I could also adjust the number of decimals, e.g.:

0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.16
0.00
0.83
0.00

Comment: example would be better.

Comment: you can't. the sum won't be available until all the records have been processed. you'd have to scan the file twice. once to get the sum, then again to do your value/sum calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scan the input twice:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{sum+= $1; next}{printf("%4.2f\n", $1/sum)}' input input
```

Comment: For fun, you can write the `input input` like this `input{,}`

Comment: Just watch out for that pesky file where all of the values it contains are zero and then `$1/sum` gets interesting :-). You need something like `printf "%4.2f\n", (sum?$1/sum:0)` or `printf "%4.2f\n", ($1?$1/sum:0)` at least. I say at least because `print (sum ? sprintf("%4.2f", $1/sum) : "NaN")` or similar might be more appropriate.

Comment: What does the "%4" part control?

Comment: @5heikki The `%4.2f` is the format string which controls the precision  and width of the output.